# Save Object in CoreData (Attributes with String, Double & Array)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am having difficulty with saving an object in CoreData.  It was working fine before but I changed three variables from a String to an Array of Strings...  image, imageDesc and attrib
I have a file called CoreDataHandler as below.

```
class CoreDataHandler: NSObject {
private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}
class func saveObject(name: String, type: String, description: String, image: [String], imageDesc: [String], attrib: [String], rating: String, address: String, lat: Double, long: Double, annoName: String) -> Bool {
    //cost: String, openingTimes: String, pets: String, 
    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CastleSave", in: context)
    let manageObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    manageObject.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    manageObject.setValue(type, forKey: "type")
    manageObject.setValue(description, forKey: "desc")
    manageObject.setValue([image], forKey: "image")
    manageObject.setValue([imageDesc], forKey: "imageDesc")
    manageObject.setValue([attrib], forKey: "attrib")
    manageObject.setValue(rating, forKey: "rating")
    manageObject.setValue(address, forKey: "address")
    manageObject.setValue(lat, forKey: "lat")
    manageObject.setValue(long, forKey: "long")
    manageObject.setValue(annoName, forKey: "annoName")

    do {
        try context.save()
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

I was using the below code for saving as a favourite

```
CoreDataHandler.saveObject(name: (txte?.name)!, type: (txte?.type)!, description: (txte?.description)!, image: (txte?.image)!, imageDesc: (txte?.imageDesc)!, attrib: (txte?.attrib)!, rating: (txte?.rating)!, address: (txte?.address)!, lat: (txte?.lat)!, long: (txte?.long)!, annoName: (txte?.annoName)!)
```

In my DataModel...
I previously had the attributes of image, imageDesc & attrib as String.
I changed this to Transformable, and the attribute CustomClass as [String] but I am struggling to see how I can save this correctly.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You're using a pattern similar to `(txte?.name)!` quite a lot, this could probably be simplified to `txte!.name`

Comment: Exactly what is the problem, a crash or nothing gets saved or ...?

Comment: You can not save an `array` in `CoreData` directly. See the available data types [here](https://i.imgur.com/RZMr3ZZ.png). Make a string from your array by using `join` function and `separate` them later after retrieving.

Comment: So I load all my data from a GeoJSON file into a MapView.  Then once I click on an annotation it loads the appropriate data.  Thats were the txte comes from, its basically the object that has been segued from previous view controller.  When I press the save button (save to coredata) Xcode completely crashes and I have to reopen Xcode.  I am saving my images as Strings.

Comment: Don't save images as strings instead save images in `documentDirectory` and save their paths into DB.

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is the first example but it is beyond me where or how did you get to creating this code. It makes it increasingly hard to help with such complex problems when core data is used the way it is here.

When you create a model your app should autogenerate files for you which may be used to communicate with core data directly. There should be subclasses of managed object named the same as in your model. So for instance

```
let manageObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
```

should be changed to

```
let castleSave = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! CastleSave
```

And you should be able to call properties directly like `castleSave.name = name`.

If you had this you would see that you can't call `castleSave.image = [image]` because if done correctly your `image` property is a `Data`. So you need to serialize these things.

So the question as it seems is how to convert an array of images to data. I guess `JSONSerialization` plus `base64` string encoding should do:

```
func dataFromImageArray(images: [UIImage]) -> Data? {
    let imageDataArray: [Data] = images.compactMap { UIImageJPEGRepresentation($0, 1.0) }
    let imageBase64Array: [String] = imageDataArray.compactMap { $0.base64EncodedString() }
    let jsonData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: imageBase64Array, options: [])
    return jsonData
}

func imageArrayFromData(data: Data) -> [UIImage] {
    guard let items = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments])) as? [String] else {
        return []
    }

    let dataItems: [Data] = items.compactMap { Data(base64Encoded: $0) }
    let images: [UIImage] = dataItems.compactMap { UIImage(data: $0) }

    return images
}
```

Pretty similar may be done for array of any objects that are convertible to data.